# Line break when no data in ggplot2

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, posixct

I am using R to plot some data.

```
Date <- c("07/12/2012 05:00:00", "07/12/2012 06:00:00", "07/12/2012 07:00:00",
      "07/12/2012 08:00:00","07/12/2012 10:00:00","07/12/2012 11:00:00")
Date <- strptime(Date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
Counts <- c("0","3","10","6","5","4")
Counts <- as.numeric(Counts)
df1 <- data.frame(Date,Counts,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(df1, aes(x=Date, y=Counts)) + geom_line(aes(group = 1))
g
```

How do I ask R not to plot data as a continuous line when there is a break in time?  I normally have a data point every hour, but sometimes there is a break (between 8 am and 10 am).  Between these points, I don't want the line to connect.  Is this possible in R?

**Edit**

Many thanks for the responses here.  My data is now in 10 second intervals, and I wish to do the same piece of analysis using this data.

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", 
                     "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", 
                     "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012", "11/12/2012"),
                     Time = c("20:16:00", "20:16:10", "20:16:20", "20:16:30", 
                     "20:16:40", "20:16:50", "20:43:30", "20:43:40", 
                     "20:43:50", "20:44:00", "20:44:10"),
                     Axis1 = c(181L, 14L, 65L, 79L, 137L, 104L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 
                     14L, 0L),
                     Steps = c(13L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)),
                .Names = c("Date", "Time", "Axis1", "Steps"),
                row.names = c(57337L, 57338L, 57339L, 57340L, 57341L, 57342L, 
                57502L, 57503L, 57504L, 57505L, 57506L), class = "data.frame")
```

I think I understand what the code is trying to do, when it adds the column 'group' to the original dataframe, but my question surrounds how I get R to know the data is now in 10 second intervals?  When I apply the first line of code to determine whether the numbers are continuous or whether there is a gap (e.g. idx <- c(1, diff(df$Time)), I get the following error:

```
Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

After my `Time` variable, do I need to add `as.POSIXct` to ensure it recognises the time correctly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You'll have to set `group` by setting a common value to those points you'd like to be connected. Here, you can set the first 4 values to say `1` and the last 2 to `2`. And keep them as factors. That is,

```
df1$grp <- factor(rep(1:2, c(4,2)))
g <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=Date, y=Counts)) + geom_line(aes(group = grp)) + 
                     geom_point()
```

**Edit:** Once you have your `data.frame` loaded, you can use this code to automatically generate the `grp` column:

```
idx <- c(1, diff(df$Date))
i2 <- c(1,which(idx != 1), nrow(df)+1)
df1$grp <- rep(1:length(diff(i2)), diff(i2))
```

**Note:** It is **important** to add `geom_point()` as well because if the `discontinuous range` happens to be the LAST entry in the data.frame, it won't be plotted (as there are not 2 points to connect the line). In this case, `geom_point()` will plot it.

As an example, I'll generate a data with more gaps:

```
# get a test data
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.POSIXct("05:00", format="%H:%M"), 
                as.POSIXct("23:00", format="%H:%M"), by="hours"))
df$Counts <- sample(19)
df <- df[-c(4,7,17,18),]

# generate the groups automatically and plot
idx <- c(1, diff(df$Date))
i2 <- c(1,which(idx != 1), nrow(df)+1)
df$grp <- rep(1:length(diff(i2)), diff(i2))
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=Counts)) + geom_line(aes(group = grp)) + 
            geom_point()
g
```

[image: ggplot2_groups]

**Edit:** For your NEW data (assuming it is `df`),

```
df$t <- strptime(paste(df$Date, df$Time), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

idx <- c(10, diff(df$t))
i2 <- c(1,which(idx != 10), nrow(df)+1)
df$grp <- rep(1:length(diff(i2)), diff(i2))
```

now plot with `aes(x=t, ...)`.

Comment: (+1) however, in this case, its more like the OP expects missing values in his data, isn't it ? :-)

Comment: Many thanks.  Is there a way of doing this automatically without looking at the individual data files (as I have > 1000 files to run in this way, and I won't probably be able to look at them one by one?).  And @Juba - yes, I would expect zeros.  In my real data, if there is 20 minutes of continuous zeros, these are deleted.

Comment: Yes, as long as you know that the interval is always 1 hour, we can do this. Give me a minute, I'll edit the post.

Comment: @Arun Ok, ok, I'll surrender :) And great edit, by the way. Too bad I can't upvote you twice !

Comment: :) thanks juba. no issues. @KT_1, of course here I assume that the all continuous values are 1 hour apart. Anything more than 1 hour apart will be given another group (until the next entry where I find >1hour difference).

Comment: @KT_1, please check my `note` as well. In short, use `+ geom_point()` as well.

Comment: @Arun.  Many thanks.  My real data is at 1o second intervals and contained in a column with just time in (called 'Time').  How do I adapt the code: idx <- c(1, diff(df$Date))
i2 <- c(1,which(idx != 1), nrow(df)+1)
df1$grp <- rep(1:length(diff(i2)), diff(i2)) ... to recognise this?

Comment: Apologies... it's in 10 second intervals

Comment: @KT_1, I've provided enough ideas and clear method. Why don't you make an attempt to do it for 10hr interval and post the code with the problem you face, so that I can guide you rather than me working on the code entirely..?

Comment: I have editted my original question @Arun with my real data.  I am still confused how to tell R that my data is every 10 seconds and not every hour.  When I change the column name I get an error message, do I need to specify the format of this time column?

Comment: @KT_1, The last edit at the bottom of the post should do it. It is **really** that simple. Changing `1` to `10`.

Comment: Many thanks @Arun - that's exactly what I wanted.  R studio was giving some odd values, but alas everything works when I just use R.  I think there is some kind of bug in R studio regards dates.

Comment: `i2 <- c(1,which(idx != 1), nrow(df)+1)` isn't `cumsum()` a better tool to do this?

Comment: How could you do this with data that had two additional groups. Say I have another group of discontinuous data that I wanted to plot simultaneously? I have data sampled by month for only 6 of 12 months of the year so I'm already grouping by Year to eliminate the connecting lines, but I also have 2 zones of data I want to plot and can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 17):

I think there is no way for R or `ggplot2` to know if there is a missing data point somewhere, apart from you to specify it with an `NA`. This way, for example :

```
df1 <- rbind(df1, list(strptime("07/12/2012 09:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), NA))
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Date, y=Counts)) + geom_line(aes(group = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) however, in this case, its more like the OP expects two groups of plots, isn't it? I mean, isn't more appropriate to set group NOT to 1, rather a grouping variable...

Answer (score 7):

[Juba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14821191/892313), to include explicit `NA`'s where you want breaks, is the best approach. Here is an alternate way to introduce those `NA`'s in the right place (without having to figure it out manually).

```
every.hour <- data.frame(Date=seq(min(Date), max(Date), by="1 hour"))
df2 <- merge(df1, every.hour, all=TRUE)
g %+% df2
```

[image]

You can do something similar with your later `df` example, after changing the dates and times into a proper format

```
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(df$Date, df$Time), 
                                   format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
every.ten.seconds <- data.frame(DateTime=seq(min(df$DateTime), 
                                             max(df$DateTime), by="10 sec"))
df.10 <- merge(df, every.ten.seconds, all=TRUE)
```

Comment: This is a very clean answer. Instead of merge, you can use [`complete`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) which will fill in NAs of every combination of variables, if you had multiple groups.

Comment: @qwr If I were writing this answer today, I probably would use something like `complete`. But `tidyr` didn't exist when I wrote this answer. Adding a new answer which shows the solution using `complete` might be useful. Feel free to do so ;)

Comment: Simple and effective answer! You could simply do `df %>% dplyr::mutate(var = if_else(condition == TRUE, NA, var)` and replace `condition == TRUE` with whatever you need.