# ggplot2 - geom_line of cumulative counts of factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the cumulative counts of level `OK` of factor `X` (*), over time (column `Date`). I am not sure what is the best strategy, whether or not I should create a new data frame with a summary column, or if there is a ggplot2 way of doing this.

**Sample data**

```
DF <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-03-01", "2018-03-01", "2018-04-01") ),
  X = factor(rep("OK", 6), levels = c("OK", "NOK")),
  Group = factor(c(rep("A", 4), "B", "B"))
)
DF <- rbind(DF, list(as.Date("2018-02-01"), factor("NOK"), "A"))
```

From similar questions I tried this:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(Date, col = Group)) + geom_line(stat='bin')
```

[image]

Using `stat='count'` (as the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286267/separating-lines-with-ggplot-geom-line-when-using-stat-count)) is even worse:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(Date, col = Group)) + geom_line(stat='count')
```

[image]

which shows the counts for factor levels (*), but not the accumulation over time.

**Desperate measure** - count with `table`

I tried creating a new data frame with counts using `table` like this:

```
cum <- as.data.frame(table(DF$Date, DF$Group))
ggplot(cum, aes(Var1, cumsum(Freq), col = Var2, group = Var2)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this with ggplot2? Do I need to create a new column with `cumsum`? If so, how should I `cumsum` the factor levels, by date?

(*) Obs: I could just filter the data frame to use only the intended levels with `DF[X == "OK"]`, but I am sure someone can find a smarter solution.

Comment: Probably it is not possible to get cumulative value in `aes` since you have got multiple groups. Otherwise `cumsum` within `aes` would have helped. Finger-crossed. Lets see if someone got some idea. In the mean time I have posted an answer using `dplyr` chain to calculate cumulative count and draw line. Have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using `dplyr` and `ggplot2` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

DF %>% group_by(Group) %>%
       arrange(Date) %>%
       mutate(Value = cumsum(X=="OK")) %>%
      ggplot(aes(Date, y=Value, group = Group, col = Group)) + geom_line()
```

[image]